# Insert query with value from Select

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-insert

I am trying to query 2 different tables with a Select and the result is a list of strings.

```
select Lock 
from [dbo].[LabelLock]
where [Value] = @Label 
UNION
select Lock
from [dbo].[ProdLock]
where [Value] = @Process
```

So far everything good. What I want is some way to insert into my **[Locks]** table a record for each result of the Select above in this way:

```
insert into [dbo].[Locks]
(Id, Locks)
values (@Id, .....)
```

so the @Id is always fixed, but the Locks should come from the Select and I want a record inserted for each result provided by the Select query. How can I achieve this in a smart way? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code doesn't look like MySQL code.  Are you sure you are using MySQL and not SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO
    [dbo].[Locks]
(
    Id,
    Locks
)
SELECT
    @Id,
    Lock 
FROM
    [dbo].[LabelLock]
WHERE
    [Value] = @Label 
UNION
SELECT
    @Id,
    Lock
FROM
    [dbo].[ProdLock]
WHERE
    [Value] = @Process
```

Comment: there is no Id to be selected in the tables. The Id doesn't come from there

Comment: You prepended the Id with an @ which indicates a parameter / variable.

So what you want to do? Is the Id column in the Locks table an automatically incremented value?

Comment: Okey, there is no need of Values keyword to indicate the values in the insert?

Comment: No, you do not need the value keyword for inserting.